# Button does not receive onPress event while TextInput is focused

Tags: react-native

I am prototyping a small twitter wall for a project and have experienced a strange problem. I have the following views structure:

```
<Animated.View style={[{flex: 1}, {marginBottom: this.bottomOffset}]}>

  <FlatList 
  ...
  keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
  ... />                

  <View style={{
     flexDirection: "row", 
     alignItems: "center", 
     minHeight: 44, 
     backgroundColor: "#cccccc"}}>

     <Octicons />

     <TextInput 
         enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
         multiline={true}
         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})} 
         value={this.state.text} 
     />

    <Octicons
         name="diff-renamed" 
         backgroundColor="transparent"
         color="black"
         style={styles.icon}
         size={24}                         
         onPress={this._handlePost} 
    />
 </View>
</Animated.View>
```

where

```
_handlePost = (e) => {
    // todo: networking
    this.setState({
        text: ""
    });
}
```

I've have shorten some parts of the code for simplicity and to make the code readable.

The problem is, when the TextInput has the focus no other Touchable receives onPress event. Once the TextInput lost the focus all other components receive onPress events.

Just for information: the TextInput get cleared once the callback onPress, in my case **_handlePost** is invoked.

See the [video](https://youtu.be/5dKuIJ6oVIY).

What might I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to persist tap events on the parent container by declaring it as ScrollView, like:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  style={[{flex: 1}, {marginBottom: this.bottomOffset}]}
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
>
  ...
  <View style={{
    flexDirection: "row", 
    alignItems: "center", 
    minHeight: 44, 
    backgroundColor: "#cccccc"}}
  >
    ...
  </View>
  ...
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: I will give a try and will give a feedback but embedding a FlatList into a ScrollView  may be a bit tricky from user perspective

Comment: You can always disable ScrollView scrolling with `scrollEnabled`. A bit hacky of course, but normal `View` doesn't support `keyboardShouldPersistTaps`.

Comment: This did the trick. I had a FlatList in the most parent View which caused the keyboard to dismiss on press. Once I have set keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} on that List the inner FlatList (displayed in modal on top of it) behaves properly.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are importing Octicons from react-native-vector-icons or expo, correct? If that is the case, they don't support an onPress method (at least according to the documentation). Try wrapping it with a Touchable.

Comment: there is no issue with onPress and the icons. I tried with a common react native button as well and it behaves the same.